# trying to write if, else statement and detect keypress

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, lua, keypress

Hi I'm trying to write a batch file that when it gets to that area of the code waits for 10 seconds and then if a certain key is pressed exits, otherwise it goes to another area of the code.
Here is what I got so far

```
SLEEP 10
IF
exit
else if
goto start
```

sorry, I don't know if this is correct. I'm just learning Lua and while similar to DOS they aren't quite the same. If anyone can fill in the gaps and fix the mistakes I would much appreciate it. The key I want to be pressed is either any or a specific key ID which

Comment: That's not Lua code. What kind of batch file is that?

Comment: To be able to write something in Lua, you should first learn a bit of it's syntax. The [Programming in Lua book](http://www.lua.org/pil/) is a good place to get started.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in batch using this

```
@echo off
choice /c abcd /n /t 5 /d d
if %errorlevel%==1 echo You chose a
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :CONTINUE
if %errorlevel%==3 echo You chose c
if %errorlevel%==4 exit >nul

:CONTINUE
REM Continue code
pause >nul
```

Usage:

In this script your options are `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Use the %errorlevel% with incrementing numbers to get the choice selected.

The `/t` switch is the timeout in seconds, in this it is 5 seconds.

The `/d` switch is the default option, use this to automatically make a choice if the command times out. In this case `d` will be the time out choice, which will exit the script.

Just tweak to fit your needs.

Comment: oh great! this was what I was looking for the last couple hours! keys that haven't been defined even trigger a "beep error" sound. I wonder if this sound can be modified somehow? :)